# How do I get Portage to download a package, and do nothing more?

Tags: gentoo, portage

After having some trouble connecting to a TLS server and then noticing that `app-misc/ca-certificates` is a year and four months behind, I got curious as to what's changed since `20140927.3.17.2`. I figured I'd just grab a copy of the package, extract everything from it, and poke around. A skim of the `emerge` manual page turned up `--fetchonly` (`-f`):

> Instead of doing any package building, just perform fetches for all packages (fetch things from SRC_URI based upon USE setting).

Sounds like what I want! Let's go.

```
caramel:~ blackl% emerge --fetchonly '='app-misc/ca-certificates-20151214.3.21
emerge: portage group access is required
```

…uhhh? Well…I don't see why not. Have root privileges.

```
caramel:~ blackl% sudo emerge --fetchonly '='app-misc/ca-certificates-20151214.3.21
Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild     U ~] app-misc/ca-certificates-20151214.3.21 [20140927.3.17.2]

The following keyword changes are necessary to proceed:
 (see "package.accept_keywords" in the portage(5) man page for more details)
# required by =app-misc/ca-certificates-20151214.3.21 (argument)
=app-misc/ca-certificates-20151214.3.21 ~amd64
```

What? No…I just want to download the package; I don't want to actually install it or make any other changes to the system.

A more thorough search of the manual page didn't turn up anything else that looked relevant (except for `--fetch-all-uri`|`-F`, which gives me the same result). Why's `emerge` insisting on privileged access and keyword changes here? What would it *really* be doing, besides just downloading a tarball, verifying it, and dumping it in the working directory or a cache somewhere?

Comment: Btw. the outdated `app-misc/ca-certificates` in stable branch is a known bug which awaits resolution - https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=561962

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question should probably be more like: "How do I get Portage to download **package sources**, and do nothing more?". The reason why it doesn't work using `emerge` is because that's how emerge is designed. emerge is simply not the right tool for doing this kind of job and hopefully will never be. To actually accomplish what you want, you have to use `ebuild` command (`man 1 ebuild`), like this:

```
ebuild <PATH_TO_EBUILD> fetch
```

This command downloads (and verifies) everything in `$SRC_URI` to your `$DISTDIR`.

To get the value of the variables:

- `<PATH_TO_EBUILD>`

  - is composed like this:
  - `<REPO_DIR>/<CATEGORY>/<PACKAGE_NAME>/<PACKAGE_NAME>-<VERSION>.ebuild`
  - https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Repository_format
- `<REPO_DIR>`: `portageq get_repo_path / gentoo`
- `$DISTDIR`: `portageq distdir`

To actually fetch the sources to a dir of your choosing, just spoof the `$DISTDIR` var like this:

```
DISTDIR=<DIR> ebuild <PATH_TO_EBUILD> fetch
```

So if you use default portage paths and want to download sources to your home dir, issue this:

```
DISTDIR=~ ebuild /usr/portage/app-misc/ca-certificates/ca-certificates-20151214.3.21.ebuild fetch
```